# How to download logs programmatically on Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How can I download the pipeline logs as a pipeline task? I need it to upload it somewhere. Thanks.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPkyU.png

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67534289/azure-devops-pipeline-logs-for-a-specific-task

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge there is no such way(may be there i am not sure) you might be looking something like this. Rest Api are there to fetch the single step logs / list of logs. Refer below MSDN docs

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/logs?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/logs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0
```

To call these apis from Azure pipeline you can use `InvokeRESTAPI@1` task, as shown in the below doc.

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops
```

Comment: According to docs, `InvokeRESTAPI@1` can only be used on agentless job which I don't. I am using self-hosted agent. Any other way for me to download logs?

Comment: then instead of using InvokeRESTAPI@1 use Inline Powershell script to call the Rest Api. There seems no straight way to get through the logs. But not sure about type of Task you use, if it's related to Msbuild then this might help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/obtaining-build-logs-with-msbuild?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

In a Powershell task uou can use the following URL to get all the logs:

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}/logs?api-version=7.1-preview.2
```

Or if you need a specific log, assuming you know the Id, you can use:

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}/environments/{environmentId}/deployPhases/{releaseDeployPhaseId}/tasks/{taskId}/logs?api-version=7.1-preview.2**
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1

You'll need to `Allow scripts to access the OAuth token` or generate a PAT (Person Access Token) with the correct permissions which you can then use in your script.